# change the display according to connexion state

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm working on PHP authentication, i want to make sure that the user is connected or not
if user is not connecet than it appears at for login | sign up, otherwise the name will be shown on the  top page nearly to Logout link
here is my code

```
    <div id="pl_header" class="container_24 NormalTopPadding">
            <ul class="acc_nav">
                        <div class="jaccess">
                            <?php if($_SESSION['niv'] != 0){?>
                                <li><a href="login.php"><span>Login</span></a></li>                     
                                <li><a href="" data-reveal-id="myModal_197"><span>Sign up</span></a></li>
                            <?php }  else {?>
                                <li><span class="user">Welcome <strong><? echo ($_GET['login']);?></strong></span></li>
                                <li id="un-login"><a href="#"><span>Logout</span></a></li>
                            <?php }?>    
                        </div>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

when i want to access to this pags it shows "Undefined variable: _SESSION". what can i do to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Your class is wrapping PDO in a very thin, inefficient layer, and doesn't make it any easier or simpler to use other than some better variable binding. You should return `$this` from a lot of your methods - that way you can chain calls for more concise, cleaner code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get data you need to user `fetchAll()` with `query()` 
I edited your code try with following code.

```
$c = new Connexion();
    $results = $c->query("select poste,client,type_contrat,desc_annonce from annonce ")->fetchAll();
     <div class="Joblist">
      <?php foreach($results as $r) { ?>
            <p class="Title">
              <span class="Ref">xxxx</span>
              <a href="details.php"><?php echo($r['poste']); ?></a>
            </p>
            <p class="Date"><span class="Fright"><?php echo($r['type_contrat']); ?></span>
             <span><a href="sector.php" class="Sectorbtn"><?php echo($r['client']); ?></a>  </span></p>
            <p><?php echo($r['desc_annonce']); ?></p>
            <p class="More"><a href="details.php">Voir plus</a></p>
      <?php }?>
     </div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: @Bojangles It won't help OP either, since `query()` doesn't return anything to use `fetchAll()` against.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll improve my self.. thanks for your advice.. I will edit the my answerer. thanks @Bojangles..

Comment: Nope, that still won't work. _Read_ OP's definition of `query()`. It doesn't return anything, so your code will fail

Comment: it shows annother error " Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\CVtheque\View\annonces.php on line 4", the fourth line is the line of the query

Comment: please check your sql query table name **'annonce'** use following code -  $results = $c->query("select poste,client,type_contrat,desc_annonce from 'annonce' ")->fetchAll();

Comment: That error message indicates that $result does NOT contain an object. this would indicate that $c->query("select poste,client,type_contrat,desc_annonce from annonce "); failed. This would indicate that either the query failed -- you need to check the value of query; or there is no database connection

Comment: this the table structure
CREATE TABLE `annonce` (
  `id_annonce` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `poste` varchar(50),
  `nombre_postes` int(11),
  `client` varchar(1000),
  `type_contrat` varchar(100),
  `desc_annonce` varchar(1000)
)
when i use this query on phpmyadmin it shows me records

Comment: Please check my second answer it is the solution for your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At finally I got the problem, following code is not necessary to your pdo connection those are change the default pdo class

```
public function query($query) {
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
    if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

public function execute() {
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}

public function resultset() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function single() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function rowCount() {
    return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}

public function lastInsertId() {
    return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
}

public function beginTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
}

public function endTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->commit();
}

public function cancelTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->rollBack();
}

public function debugDumpParams() {
    return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
 }
```

---

use following code it will work fine..

```
<?php

class Connexion {

private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $pass = "";
private $dbname = "annonce";
public $dbh;
private $stmt;

public function __construct() {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        // Set options
        $options = array(
            \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try {
            $this->dbh = new \PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);

        }catch (\PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connexion Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
}

public function Connecton(){
            return $this->dbh;  
}

}
?>

<?php

$c = new Connexion();
$c = $c->Connecton();
    $results = $c->query("select poste,client,type_contrat,desc_annonce from annonce ")->fetchAll();
    ?>
     <div class="Joblist">
      <?php foreach($results as $r) { ?>
            <p class="Title">
              <span class="Ref">xxxx</span>
              <a href="details.php"><?php echo($r['poste']); ?></a>
            </p>
            <p class="Date"><span class="Fright"><?php echo($r['type_contrat']); ?></span>
             <span><a href="sector.php" class="Sectorbtn"><?php echo($r['client']); ?></a>  </span></p>
            <p><?php echo($r['desc_annonce']); ?></p>
            <p class="More"><a href="details.php">Voir plus</a></p>
      <?php }?>
     </div>
```